# What is a euphemism for "slurred speech"?

Tags: translation

"Slurred speech" is not just a past participle modifying a noun. It is actually a casual way to say the medical condition "dysarthria". I was just wondering if there was a Japanese euphemism analogous to "slurred speech".

Comment: I may be wrong but I think this question is asking for translation without an attempt to translate and thus is off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[吃]{ども}る` means "to stutter", although I don't know if that completely overlaps with "slurred speech", or if it necessarily implies anything like a stroke, concussion, etc.

Comment: I have heard colleagues use 吃る to refer to another colleague with congenital speech issues (having not met the colleague, I can't tell for sure, but it sounded more like slur than stutter). So this might be the word you are looking for.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the confirmation. 「吃る」 sounds about as best as I can recommend. I do wonder what slurred speech sounds like in Japanese, spoken by native or non-native alike. I also wonder if it is even possible to slur speech in Chinese (but that would be a different thread).

Comment: @shinmai_psb The typical [吃]{ども}り/[吃音]{きつおん} is like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQh1WqNYNCw from 0:29「この、サイレントヒ、ヒ、ヒ、ヒ、ヒルをし、しようっと、と思った理由は、これが普通に淀橋で安売りし、し、し、し、してたから・・・」

Comment: @shinmai_psb The typical ろれつが回らない is like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApCqIwoQmIo from 0:30

Answer (score 3):

[Glancing on alc](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=slurred%20speech&ref=sa), it seems you can describe someone's words as 不明瞭 (as in 不明瞭な言葉・発語) or use the expression ろれつがまわらない, which is basically "to speak inarticulately." edict includes "slurring" in its definition of this.

[This page](http://www.naoru.com/noukousoku.htm) uses the phrase ろれつがまわらない in reference to stroke victims.

Particularly this example seems to match that more medical sort of meaning:

> If you have a loss of coordination and slurred speech in the cold outside, you should come inside right away.
>   寒い戸外にいてもし筋肉運動が失調し、言葉が不明瞭になってきたら、すぐに室内に入るべきである。

Discussion with user @Chocolate in chat has led me to believe that 吃る, while indicative of a similar speech phenomenon, is used more for stuttering/stammering in the sense of getting caught on the initial sounds of words and *not* the unintelligible stream of sound that slurred speech tends to be.

Nevertheless I am not 100% sure. My answer is based only on research and not prior knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add the following two terms to the existing answers.

> 言語障害
>   speech impediment
>
> [構語障害](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/homemed/11080/m0u/)
>   [dysarthria](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/dysarthria/basics/definition/con-20035008)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> [言葉]{ことば}or[発音]{はつおん}or言っていること　 が　 [聞]{き}き[取]{と}りづらいor聞き取りにくい
>   or
>   [滑舌]{かつぜつ}が[悪]{わる}い　(Not good at speaking smoothly and clearly)